# How to share objects with users in a many-to-many relationship?

Tags: sharing, relationships

I have a user to object many-to-many relationship and would like to give users read access to all objects that they are related to.

In my data model there are three objects: User, Junction, and Foo. User and Foo both have a lookup relationship to the Junction object. What is the easiest way to give users read access to the Foo objects that have the same Junction object as them?

Comment: Can you explain your question a bit more? I am unable to understand what you want to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use Apex sharing together with trigger on Junction object.
For example, if there are some records of Junction object created - create FooShare objects with related Foo records for related users, the same for removal - remove FooShare objects.

Here you can see some examples:

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2009/11/25/programmatically-creating-sharing-rules-with-apex/
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_bulk_sharing_creating_with_apex.htm

Important note - please, ensure that your trigger is bulkified enough - that may quickly hit limits.

Comment: This is the route I took. Although I had to create insert/update triggers on both the Foo and User object, and not on the Junction object. A trigger on the Junction object would not fire at the appropriate times (e.g. User or Foo's Junction object change).

Comment: You are right. But I think that trigger on Junction is still needed.
Imagine if there are some of them removed - you need to delete corresponding apex share. As well as add new one if you insert Junction object