# How to share objects with users in a many-to-many relationship - revisited 2023?

Tags: sharing, sharing-rule, apex-managed-sharing

Is the answer to this 7 year old post [How to share objects with users in a many-to-many relationship?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/87769/how-to-share-objects-with-users-in-a-many-to-many-relationship) still correct?

Do share any more recent links on this subject if you know of them.